# how get graph data using python from https://www.bayut.com/index/sale-prices-2-bed-apartments-al-raha-beach.html

Tags: python, web-scraping

I need to get graph data from the above website is there any way to get the data, i've checked the similar question but i didn't get any result for those questions

**https://www.bayut.com/index/sale-prices-2-bed-apartments-al-raha-beach.html**

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I've pulled all the data available on this page except the graph data. I didn't know  whether is there process to pull graph data are not

Comment: i didn't find any relevant material for graph data scraping is there any method, please let me know @Jack